# pandas: How to get the value_counts() above a threshold

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I get the value_counts above a threshold? I tried

```
df[df[col].value_counts(dropna=False) > 3]
```

to get all counts greater than 3, but I am getting

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df.groupby(col)[col].transform('size')>3]
```

Or with `value_counts`:

```
counts = df[col].value_counts(dropna=False) 
valids = counts[counts>3].index

df[df[col].isin(valids)]
```

Another approach with `value_counts` and `map`:

```
counts = df[col].value_counts(dropna=False)
df[df[col].map(counts)>3]
```

Comment: .map reads and works great. Thanks for the quick answer. To get the original value_counts()-Layout I did df[df[col].map(counts)>3][col].value_counts().

Comment: @AndreasInfo that's overkilled, it's just `counts[counts>3]` or as in BENY's answer `df[col].value_counts.loc[lambda x: x>3]`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `isin` and chain with your original `value_counts`

```
out = df[df.col.isin(df[col].value_counts(dropna=False).loc[lambda x : x>3].index)].copy()
```

Also Let us try `filter`

```
out = df.groupby(col).filter(lambda x : len(x)>3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with `value_counts`, here's a simple solution:

```
df[col].value_counts(dropna=False)[df[col].value_counts(dropna=False) > 3]
```